# MySQL copying data from table rows to another table row in different table

Tags: mysql

I am still learning SQL tables and have become stuck on this.
I am trying to copy data into a table row from another tables information based on conditions of both tables.
My example is below as this is the only way I can think to explain in properly. The user completes the values of cs and cc by way of a form (which is all done and working properly) and then the values of cp,ca and cd should populate from the other tables information.

```
    Table1
    columns =   id    cs      cc     cp     ca     cd
    rows    =    1    Table2  a       ?      ?      ?
                 2    Table3  a       ?      ?      ?

    Table2
    columns =   id    cc      cp      ca     cd     date
    rows    =    1    a        1       2      3      2015-28-04
                 2    a        4       5      6      2015-29-04
                 3    b        7       8      9      2015-28-04
                 4    b        10      11     12     2015-29-04
```

I need to populate the values of cp,ca and cd in row 1 of table1 by using the values 1,2 and 3 in row1 in table2. The conditions are that the value of cs in row 1 of table1 equals the name of table we want to use and then the value of cc in row 1 of table1 equals the value of cc in row1 of that table and todays date.

I will then try setting up a cronjob so that the values update each day with the new values.

I have tried using the INSERT INTO .... SELECT function but that copies columns not data and I am not sure if its possible to do what I want with the conditions I need. Any help on what code I should use to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Table2, Table3 etc is a finite list (IE the table name from Table1.cs is a known set) then you either need to do multiple updates of the form:

```
UPDATE Table1,Table2 
SET Table1.cp = Table2.cp,
    Table1.ca = Table2.ca,
    Table1.cd = Table2.cd
WHERE Table1.cs = 'Table2' AND Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.cc = Table2.cc;

UPDATE Table1,Table3 
SET Table1.cp = Table3.cp,
    Table1.ca = Table3.ca,
    Table1.cd = Table3.cd
WHERE Table1.cs = 'Table3' AND Table1.id = Table3.id AND Table1.cc = Table3.cc;

etc for Table4, Table5 ...
```

OR If the table names are variable and unknown then you will need to look into using mysql Prepared Statements, which is a considerably more complex subject. See here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html